# ReactJS, MeteorJS, and MongoDB: Getting collection from different collection value?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Okay, so, I have a component with a function getPhotos(), which is taking in a string from parent props:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

// data
import { Cats } from '../api/collections/galleries.js';

export default class...
 getPhotos() {
   let gallery = this.props.galleryName; // gallery = "Cats"
```

Now, I want to use this string "Cats" to access a collection from mongo db, so I tried using window["Cats"], but I don't think it is on the window object:

```
   let photoData = window[gallery].find().fetch(); // window[Cats] and window["Cats"] returns undefined
   return photoData;
}
```

Everything in meteor seems to be working, publish and subscribe.

Any ideas how I can do this using React components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Meteor.connection._stores[gallery]._getCollection().find().fetch();
```